# Xamarin iOS support for Xcode 11.2.1 GM

Tags: xamarin

After I compile my XamariniOS application and try to distribute it from Xcode 11.2.1 I still get the error that my tools is not compatible and I need to upgrade to 11.2.1

I re-installed the Xcode tools as well from the command line.

Comment: Hi , which is the version of Visual Studio and the iOS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existing tools work but need to update the deployment target from 9.0 to minimum 12.1